# why is FileReader not a class in NetBeans?

Tags: java, eclipse, netbeans, filereader

So I just switched to NetBeans today because my eclipse had been crashing for a bizillion times. However when I am learning something on reading files, I can't seem to import the class for `FileReader`.

When I try to import something for `FileReader`, it just asks me if I want to create method `FileReader(java.io.File)`. Is this just a difference between Eclipse and Netbeans?

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;



File file1 = new File("test.txt");

try(BufferedReader bf1 = new BufferedReader(FileReader(file1))){


}catch (IOException ex) {
       System.out.println("haha");
}
```

Comment: You're missing the `new`, it should be `new FileReader(file1)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You simply haven't imported it - you either need a wildcard import:

```
import java.io.*;
```

or the specific import:

```
import java.io.FileReader;
```

As noted by Titus, you're also missing a `new` before you use `FileReader`. This:

```
try(BufferedReader bf1 = new BufferedReader(FileReader(file1))){
```

should be:

```
try(BufferedReader bf1 = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file1))){
```

Now it's possible that you're used to Eclipse importing things automatically for you more than Netbeans - looking in common packages (or even all packages) for the type that you mention, and offering to import it for you. I don't know about the Netbeans functionality here, but it wouldn't surprise me if it's a little different.

I'd also encourage you to avoid `FileReader` anyway - it doesn't let you specify the encoding used to read the file. As of Java 7 there's a more convenient method in [`java.nio.Files`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html) anyway:

```
try (BufferedReader reader = Files.newBufferedReader(file1.toPath())) {
    ...
}
```

Or start off with a `Path`:

```
Path file1 = Paths.of("test.txt");
try (BufferedReader reader = Files.newBufferedReader(path)) {
    ...
}
```

This will use UTF-8 by default, or you can specify an encoding if you wish.

Comment: I have a doubt.I use eclipse and it suggests me to import a package if it is necessary.Doesn't netbeans show such suggestions??

Comment: @MathewsMathai: As I said, I don't know about the functionality here - and I wouldn't be surprised if different options could affect it too.

Comment: @JonSkeet I feel so stupid right now ! And thank you for the explanations that go far and beyond!!

Answer (score 3):

You're missing two things here. First, you must import the class:

```
import java.io.FileReader;
```

Second, `FileReader` is a class, not a method - you're missing the `new` operator:

```
try (BufferedReader bf1 = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file1))) {
    // Here ---------------------------------^
    // etc...
```